# Find Out If a Function has been Called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am programming in Python, and I am wondering if i can test if a function has been called in my code

```
def example():
    pass
example()
#Pseudocode:
if example.has_been_called:
   print("foo bar")
```

How would I do this?

Comment: I wrote a [counting decorator](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577534-counting-decorator/?in=user-4173873) that when applied will tell you how many times a function was called. You can adapt this to your need if you want.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with this information?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I have two class methods and the second should only be called if the first has processed the data at least once. I liked the counting decorator approach paired with a guarding assert at the beginning of the second method. I am not a big fan of nested methods, but if a better approach for this exists I like to hear

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If it's OK for the function to know its own name, you can use a function attribute:

```
def example():
    example.has_been_called = True
    pass
example.has_been_called = False


example()

#Actual Code!:
if example.has_been_called:
   print("foo bar")
```

You could also use a decorator to set the attribute:

```
import functools

def trackcalls(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.has_been_called = True
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.has_been_called = False
    return wrapper

@trackcalls
def example():
    pass


example()

#Actual Code!:
if example.has_been_called:
   print("foo bar")
```

Comment: It's interesting to know that the function can get an attribute because everything in Python is an object. Functions are objects of the "function" class. And you can assign an attribute to an instance because you have not to declare variables in Python, so you can assign them at runtime.

Comment: Notice that using the function attribute will fail a mypy check

Comment: @DanielBraun In what way will it fail a mypy check?

Answer (score 4):

A minimal example using [`unittest.mock.Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) from the standard library:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

def example():
    pass

example_mock = Mock(side_effect=example)
example_mock()
#Pseudocode:
if example_mock.called:
   print("foo bar")
```

Console output after running the script:

```
foo bar
```

This approach is nice because it doesn't require you to modify the `example` function itself, which is useful if you want to perform this check in some unit-testing code, without modifying the source code itself (EG to store a `has_been_called` attribute, or wrap the function in a decorator).

### Explanation

As described in [the documentation for the `unittest.mock.Mock` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock), the `side_effect` argument to the `Mock()` constructor specifies "a function to be called whenever the Mock is called".

The `Mock.called` attribute specifies "a boolean representing whether or not the mock object has been called".

The `Mock` class has other attributes you may find useful, EG:

> `call_count`: An integer telling you how many times the mock object has been called
>
> `call_args`: This is either None (if the mock hasn’t been called), or the arguments that the mock was last called with
>
> `call_args_list`: This is a list of all the calls made to the mock object in sequence (so the length of the list is the number of times it has been called). Before any calls have been made it is an empty list

The `Mock` class also has convenient methods for making assert statements based on how many times a `Mock` object was called, and what arguments it was called with, EG:

> `assert_called_once_with(*args, **kwargs)`: Assert that the mock was called exactly once and that that call was with the specified arguments

Answer (score 3):

We can use mock.Mock

```py
from unittest import mock


def check_called(func):
    return mock.Mock(side_effect=func)


@check_called
def summator(a, b):
    print(a + b)


summator(1, 3)
summator.assert_called()
assert summator.called == True
assert summator.call_count > 0

summator.assert_called_with(1, 3)

summator.assert_called_with(1, 5)  # error
# AssertionError: Expected call: mock(1, 5)
# Actual call: mock(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) functions have been around since the 1960s. In python you can use them as decorators on your **example()** function.

The standard memoization function looks something like this:

```
def memoize(func):
    memo = {}
    def wrapper(*args):
        if not args in memo:
            memo[args] = func(*args)
        return memo[args]
    return wrapper
```

and you decorate your function like this:

```
@memoize
def example():
    pass
```

In python3.2, you can use the [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) instead of the memoziation function.

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def example():
     pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a decorator that will watch all your functiona, using colorama, and return a nice output.

```
try:
    import colorama
except ImportError:
    class StdClass: pass
    def passer(*args, **kwargs): pass
    colorama = StdClass()
    colorama.init = passer
    colorama.Fore = StdClass()
    colorama.Fore.RED = colorama.Fore.GREEN = ''

def check_for_use(show=False):
    if show:
        try:
            check_for_use.functions
        except AttributeError:
            return
        no_error = True
        for function in check_for_use.functions.keys():
            if check_for_use.functions[function][0] is False:
                print(colorama.Fore.RED + 'The function {!r} hasn\'t been called. Defined in "{}" '.format(function, check_for_use.functions[function][1].__code__.co_filename))
                no_error = False
        if no_error:
            print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + 'Great! All your checked function are being called!')
        return check_for_use.functions
    try:
        check_for_use.functions
    except AttributeError:
        check_for_use.functions = {}
        if colorama:
            colorama.init(autoreset=True)

    def add(function):
        check_for_use.functions[function.__name__] = [False, function]
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            check_for_use.functions[function.__name__] = [True, function]
            function(*args, **kwargs)
        return func
    return add

@check_for_use()
def hello():
    print('Hello world!')

@check_for_use()
def bonjour(nb):
    print('Bonjour tout le monde!')


# hello(); bonjour(0)

hello()


check_for_use(True) # outputs the following
```

Output:

```
Hello world!
The function 'bonjour' hasn't been called. Defined in "path_to_file.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a variable and increment it in the function. Later you can check if it's 1 or >= 0.