# Check if a function was callled

Tags: python

I want to check if a function was called inside a Python script.

My current solution is the following:

```
def _print_error(msg):
    print(msg)
    print("Default error message.")
    _print_error.was_called = True


_print_error.was_called = False
```

I can check if `_print_error` was called by checking `_print_error.was_called`.

Another possible way to do this is to set a class and define a static variable, that is changed whenever the class is instanced.The `__init__` can print the messages and change the `was_called` variable.

Is there a better way of achieving the same results?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882280/find-out-if-a-function-has-been-called

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question. I'll close it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a decorator to set the flag:

```
from functools import wraps

def flag_when_called(func):
    func.was_called = False

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        func.was_called = True
        return result

    return wrapper
```

Note that I only set the flag when the call successfully completes (e.g. if an exception is raised the flag is *not* set). You can swap the order (and directly `return func(*args, **kwargs)` if you want to set the flag even if an exception was raised.

Just apply that to the function:

```
@flag_when_called
def _print_error(msg):
    print(msg)
    print("Default error message.")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to do what you do. If you do it often you can write a decorator for this:

```
import functools

def trackcalls(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.was_called = True
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.was_called = False
    return wrapper

@trackcalls
def _print_error(msg):
    print(msg)
    print("Default error message.")


_print_error()

# and then check it:
if _print_error.was_called:
   print("Alarm!")
```