# Is there a numpy flag to store arbitrary information?

Tags: python, numpy, metadata

I need a way to store some attribute related to a NumPy dataset (i.e. ndarray) **without** changing the content of the dataset itself. That of course means that the information cannot be stored in the cells of the table itself. I tried looking at [flags](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html) but apparently the "array flags cannot be set arbitrarily". Just to make things clear, let me give a trivial example. Say the dataset goes through a "pipeline" where it is "cleaned" in some way. Now I want a flag type thing to mark this dataset "cleaned" so that down the line the cleaning operation is not repeated on those marked cleaned and is only performed on unmarked ones. How would I achieve something like this without writing this information in a table cell? (Please don't interpret this example literally, it is only a contrived example to demonstrate my point)

EDIT: Ideally, it would be great if this could be done without "significantly" affecting the read/write time on the ndarray

Comment: are you hoping to store a copy of the dataset in the code? which controls/technologies are you using, perhaps post a code example. For example a common place to store arbitrary information in say winform controls is Tag

Comment: It's Numpy. Is that what you mean by technology? Plus yes, it would need the flexibility to handle both views and copies.

Comment: ah sorry, for some reason I came across this looking for C# questions and i didn't recognise numpy without the capitalisation! is there any specific reason why it has to be stored inside the dataset? would it not be best to store the dataset and the extra data within a singular class?

Comment: No worries. And I think my phrasing was not clear but I meant that the information **cannot** be stored inside the dataset. So, ideally I am looking for a flag of some sort.

Comment: ndarray flags are like permissions on the array and do not maintain its state.  you can attach a flag when the pipeline cleansing function is called on the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882280/find-out-if-a-function-has-been-called)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stash it in the dtype.  Example:

```
arr = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
arr.dtype = [('value', int), ('here is a pile of extra data', 'V0')]
```

What we've done is to change the dtype from int to `[int, 'V']`, where `V` aka `V0` means "void data of zero bytes."  So that extra part of the dtype takes no space, but has a name which can be an arbitrary string.  And you can have more than one such column.

Now you can get the original data like this:

```
arr['value']
```

Or:

```
arr = arr.view(np.recarray) # enable attribute access
arr.value
```

If you're not familiar with compound dtypes,  they are used in what NumPy calls "structured arrays" or sometimes "recarrays."

To retrieve just the extra strings:

```
arr.dtype.names[1:]
```

Gives you:

```
('here is a pile of extra data',)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer -- this is a really neat workaround! The only nitpick I have for my use-case is that it apparently "significantly" increases read-time (and maybe I should mention this in my question since I admittedly did not ask for a "fast" solution). As a quick example, using arr from your post (and arr2 being the same array but without compound dtype):  % timeit arr["value"]  
111 ns ± 0.234 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)  
%timeit arr2  
19.9 ns ± 0.106 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

Comment: Do you think there is a way around this?

Comment: @chainD: 90 extra nanoseconds isn't a significant increase, especially since it doesn't scale with the size of the array. You're not actually reading the array's data in either of your timings.

Comment: @user2357112 By "significant" I was of course referring to the percentage increase from the non-compound case. Having said that, it appears that you are spot on regarding the point that this difference does not scale with array size (which is what I was concerned about). Thank you!