# Python : Cannot use the has_been_called attribute for a function

Tags: python

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you. The problem I'm having is that when the scoreboard function runs is the  `if cof.has_been_called: print("1 - 0")` part works but if the answer given by the player is wrong then it throws the 'function' object has no attribute 'has_been_called' error and I dont know how to get it to work properly without and I don't know how to fix it.

````
#at the end you go back through and see the ones you got wrong and it tells you the correct answer
import random

inccorrect = ["Good try but its wrong.", "Not quite the answer, you gave it a good shot though."]
correct = ["That is correct.", "Correct."]

def cof():
    print(random.choice(correct))

def incf():
    print(random.choice(inccorrect))

def MQ1():
    print("What does 2 + 2 =")
    answer = input("Enter the answer:")
    if answer == "4":
        cof()
        cof.has_been_called = True
    else:
        incf()
        incf.has_been_called = True

def MQ2():
    print("Lets make these questions harder.")
    print("What does 4³ =")
    answer = input("Enter the answer:")
    if answer == "64":
        cof()
    else:
        incf()

def MQ3():
    print("Lets see how far you can get!")
    print("What does 6*10⁴ = ")
    answer = input("Enter the answer:")
    if answer == "60000":
        cof()
    else:
        incf()

#scoreboards keeps count of how many Qs you have gotten right or wrong
#need to check the answers
#need to count right and wrong answers and show above the next answer
def scoreboard():
    print("0 - 0")
    MQ1()
    if cof.has_been_called:
        print("1 - 0")
    elif incf.has_been_called:
        print("0 - 1")


#to avoid just printing out everything at once need to check if each question has been answered
def main():
    scoreboard()
main()```
````

Comment: You can set "cof.has_been_called" to "False" directly after defining the "cof" function.

Comment: you have to set the `has_been_called` variable to be true inside the function
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882280/find-out-if-a-function-has-been-called

Comment: While @MichaelButscher 's comment will help you fix the current issue, just a friendly reminder that you are setting a flag that a specific function has been called at some point in time. If you are planing to use the same "strategy" for your MQ2, MQ3, ... functions, it will fail, unless you reset that flag every time. So why not get rid of this flag altogether and make your MQ functions return booleans instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Out If a Function has been Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882280/find-out-if-a-function-has-been-called)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `has_been_called` inside function to be true and then set it false by default outside the function to access it.
[Find Out If a Function has been Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882280/find-out-if-a-function-has-been-called) 
 Same has to be done for all the functions if you want to find their Call Status.

```
def cof():
    cof.has_been_called = True #For it to turn true when its called
    print(random.choice(correct))
cof.has_been_called = False #for it to be false by default
```

Although if you are trying to make a quizzing program, this is not the desirable way to do it.
You can have a list holding the scores in `int`
`scores = [0,0] #at the top`
Then you can just increment the respective score index if a correct or incorrect answer is received.

```
def cof():
    print(random.choice(correct))
    scores[0] += 1

def incf():
    print(random.choice(inccorrect))
    scores[1] += 1
```

This can later be printed in this way

```
print("{} - {}".format(scores[0], scores[1]))
```