# Make class method able to check if it has been called

Tags: python

Here is a nice way to make a function object self-aware and able to check if it has been called (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882280/find-out-if-a-function-has-been-called)):

```
def example():
    example.has_been_called = True
    pass
example.has_been_called = False


example()

#Actual Code!:
if example.has_been_called:
   print("foo bar")
```

How can I translate this solution to a class instance method?

I have tried this:

```
class Example:
    def method_one(self):
        self.method_one.has_been_called = True
        pass

    def method_two(self):
        self.method_two.has_been_called = True
        pass

example = Example()
example.method_one()

#Actual Code!:
if example.method_one.has_been_called:
   print("foo bar")
```

but I keep getting:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\python
> projects\dog\tests.py", line 8, in <module>
>     example.run()   File "c:\python projects\dog\tests.py", line 4, in run
>     self.run.has_been_called = True AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'has_been_called'
```

Comment: There is no classmethod in your code, since `run()` is missing the `@classemthod` decorator.

Comment: You speak of a class method, but then declare and call the method as an instance method. Do you want the `has_been_called` variable to be different for each instance of the class?

Comment: @trincot Yes, thanks, I mean instance method, question corrected.

Comment: Why do you care specifically that a method has been called, as opposed to checking for a side effect that it has if called?

Comment: @chepner I have a custom context manager that stores a list of functions and executes them upon exit. In real code those functions disconnect http requests sessions, but in testing, they are just fakes that do nothing (I could probably make them return something and check based on that) so there is no side effect. So I am looking for a minimal way to check if those disconnectors have been executed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add logging? Adding attributes and setting them in each method doesn't sound like *"a minimal way to check if those disconnectors have been executed"*... A print or log line seems very minimal

Comment: The `mock` library already has this functionality. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance methods are in fact members of the class. If you want to know whether an method has been called on a specific object, you should make the indicator a boolean member of the instance:

```
class Example:
    has_been_called = False
    def run(self):
        self.has_been_called = True
```

After `example = Example()`, `example.has_been_called` will be true if and only if `example.run()` has been called

If you want to know whether the method has been called on any object, you should make the indicator a member of the class:

```
class Example:
    has_been_called = False
    def run(self):
        Example.has_been_called = True  # global
        # self.__class__.has_been_called = True   # per sub_class
```

Here `Example.has_been_called` (also accessible for any instance from Example) would be true if and only if it has been called on one instance. The difference between the global and per sub-class way only matters if you have subclasses.

For a class method, the method already receives a class object and not an instance, so it would be:

```
class Example:
    has_been_called = False
    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        Example.has_been_called = True  # global
        # cls.has_been_called = True    # per sub_class
```

Beware in the per sub-class way, the attribute is set on the subclass, so you should examine it only from an instance.

Even if it is possible, you would have no reason to set an attribute on the method itself. The code should be:

```
class Example:
    has_been_called = False
    def run(self):
        Example.run.has_been_called = True
```

but it would be non Pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `dict` to store the functions that have been run.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.has_been_called = {}

    def run(self):
        self.has_been_called["run"] = True

example = Example()
example.run()

#Actual Code!:
try:
    if example.has_been_called["run"]:
        print("foo bar")
except KeyError:
    pass
```

If you comment `example.run()`, no error is raised.

Using a dictionary also allows you to apply the same process to other methods without creating a ton of variables.

Answer (score 1):

As you want each instance to have its own `has_been_called` flag, then you shouldn't attempt to define `has_been_called` on the method, as the method exists on the class object, not on the instance (`self`).

Instead, define it as an attribute on the instance object (`self`). So just skip the `.run` part:

```
class Example:
    def run(self):
        self.has_been_called = True

example = Example()
example.run()

#Actual Code!:
if example.has_been_called:
   print("foo bar")
```

If you want to have a separate flag for each method, then use a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.has_been_called = defaultdict(bool)

    def run(self):
        self.has_been_called["run"] = True

example = Example()
example.run()

if example.has_been_called["run"]:
   print("foo bar")
```

Comment: Maybe the example was not clear enough (I have updated it now), but I need to check only if specific method has been ran. So if there were some other methods  on `Example` class other than `run`, I want to be able check each one of them separately.

Comment: Then I suggest a dictionary. See update.

Answer (score 1):

Every use of `self.run` produces a *new* instance of `method`, not the actual function bound to `Example.run`. You need a reference to the actual function, which you can get through the special name `__class__`, which here will refer to the static class `Example`. You also need to ensure the attribute is initialized (though you don't need any special magic here; the name `run` is bound to an ordinary function at this point and doesn't need to be used as an attribute).

```
class Example:
    def run(self):
        __class__.run.has_been_called = True

    run.has_been_called = False
```

If instead you want to update an override in a subclass, use `type(self)` instead of `__class__`.

Comment: The only problem is that, if you needed more methods, you would need to create a variable for each method.

Comment: So? You can put the initialization in a loop. You could probably also define a decorator to that handles the initialization and the update of each variable, though that would incur the overhead of calling a wrapper on every call at runtime. You could probably do something trickier so that the wrapper, the first time it is called, re-patches the original class with the original function to avoid further updates to the flag. That's a lot of work, though, for something that I suspect isn't really of use except for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use .'s in variable names:

```
class Example:
    def method_one(self):
        self.method_one_has_been_called = True
    def method_two(self):
        self.method_two_has_been_called = True

example = Example()
example.method_one()

#Actual Code!:
if example.method_one_has_been_called:
   print("foo bar")
```

Output:

```
foo bar
```

Comment: The problem with this is that **you need to create a variable for every function**, if you want to track every function in a class. Create a dict to store function names and when it has been run.